# Showing input fields based on user choice (select)

Tags: javascript, select, input

So I have select on my page and based on user choice I want to show that amount of input fields to him and then do something with it in php script.

It looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Qyr.png

And if user chooses 3 then 3 input fields should appear if 2 then 2 etc. without reloading page. What should be used here any js or something?

Comment: Do you have any code that you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an already existing form f, you could create the input elements dynamically by looping x times where x is the selected number of inputs required, so something like

```
for ( var i=0;i<x;i++){
    var inputText = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
    inputText.setAttribute('type',"text");
    inputText.setAttribute('name',"mark" + i);
    f.append(inputText);
}
```

Comment: You're not considering the existence of a select element where the user can change the number of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet, you can run and check it. It also preserves inputs values in case of number of inputs reduce.

```js
var inputNumber = document.getElementById('input-number');
inputNumber.addEventListener('change', changeNumberOfInputs);

function changeNumberOfInputs(event) {
  var desiredInputs = parseInt(event.target.value);
  var inputsForm = document.getElementById('inputs-form');
  var actualInputs = inputsForm.getElementsByTagName('input').length;
  if(actualInputs < desiredInputs) {
    for(var i=0; i<(desiredInputs - actualInputs); i++) {
      inputsForm.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
    }
  }
  else if(actualInputs > desiredInputs) {
    for(var i=0; i<(actualInputs - desiredInputs); i++) {
      var lastInput = inputsForm.getElementsByTagName('input');
      lastInput = lastInput[lastInput.length - 1];
      inputsForm.removeChild(lastInput);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="input-number">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<form id="inputs-form">
  <input />
</form>
```

Comment: You should add, that there is 1 input field onload, and not 0!

Comment: Thanks. Just fixed

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, is to create all 6 of the Input fields. Then hide them all as standard, and do `document.getElementById(id).style` to get the style. Then call a function when the Select changes, and use the selected value to uncover the hidden inputs!

As @Arthur Cantarela stated, this is a bad practice in JS.
Alternatively, you could put them in a div, and change the div's innerHTML according to how many you need!

Comment: Create unused elements and hide them is a bad practice in DOM manipulation.

Comment: I didn't know. I rarely develop things in JS and HTML!

Answer (score -1):

You could use ng-repeat in angularjs and bind the number select to the repeat expression.

Comment: Using angular just to perform this simple task is like using a bomb to kill a fly. There's simple pure js solutions.

Comment: maybe but there's nothing wrong with using a library. I don't think your solution is particularly simple either.

Comment: Actually there is: adding js libraries requires more js data to be loaded and processed client-side, making your application slower. The 'simplicity' of my solution is about using js native dom manipulation